# Get value from ajax and place in variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, switch-statement

I am returning a value frokm ajax call. I need to put this value in a text box (which works) and then take that same number and use it as a switch variable. this is what I have tried. I am unable to save the return value as a seperate variable to use in the switch command.

```
  $.ajax({ /* START AJAX */

            type: "POST",
            url: "actionprt.php", 
            data: {"loadnumber": loadnumber}, 
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(result){

          $("#prtload1").val(result.Load1); // single digit integer returned
          var cnt = $("#prtload1").val();
          switch (cnt) {
                case 0:
                    $("#wb_prtload10dot").toggle();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $("#wb_prtload11dot").toggle();
                    break;  
                }
          $("#prtload2").val(result.Load2);
          $("#prtload3").val(result.Load3);

          }

          }); /* END OF AJAX */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cnt` contains a string, not a number. Either use `parseInt()`:

```
var cnt = parseInt($("#prtload1").val());
```

Or use strings in the switch:

```
case "0":
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c6fbna05/

Comment: Thank you much. worked like a charm. Wish I asked sooner, would have saved hours of frustration.